# Значение из $_SERVER подставляется в mysqli запрос

Tags: php

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - возвращает строку '/electricity'. При помощи substr удаляю слэш и получаю electricity. При отправке запроса оно не может найти таблицу с таким названием. Хотя, когда я на прямую вставляю в запрос название таблицы 'electricity' он норм. отрабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
require '../database/db.php';

$table = substr(1,$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);


$prev = htmlspecialchars($_POST['prev']);
$curr = htmlspecialchars($_POST['curr']);
$sum = htmlspecialchars($_POST['sum']);


$query = Data_Base::query("INSERT INTO `{$table}`(`previous_record`,`current_record`,`sum`) VALUES ({$prev},{$curr},{$sum})");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

У вас ошибка в параметрах. Поменяйте местами **1** и **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**

### SQL Инъекция

Остерегайтесь подстановки непроверенных параметров от пользователя в запрос базы данных. Обратившись на адрес:

```
http://site.ru/table VALUES (1,2,3)`;DROP DATABASE `name`;INSERT INTO
```

В данном случае, злоумышленник получит возможность удалить вашу базу данных если имеется возможность выполнить несколько запросов. Это один из вариантов возможной атаки.

Пользуйтесь подготовленными запросами с проверкой параметров.

### Полезные ссылки

[Документация по substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)

[Подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Поменял параметры, результат не изменился. Я обращаюсь к этому файлу через ajax. Такое чувство, что во время submit`a формы, сайт перезагружается и $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] в файле-обработчике то ли не успевает взять uri, то ли не тот uri, что ожидаетя берет...

Comment: [хотя выглядит норм...](https://www.screencast.com/t/gqu0in1VYX)

Comment: Проверьте переменные через дебаггер (xdebug) на локальном хосте или через var_dump и посмотрите какой запрос генерируется. Если не умеете дебажить, то перенесите запрос в переменную, например $query. после этого перед выполнением запроса напишите var_dump($table, $query). На экран выведутся 2 строки с содержимым переменных и тогда будет понятно где ошибка. После var_dump можете поставить die() чтобы прервать выполнения скрипта, но лучше научитесь работать с дебаггером в IDE.

Comment: И еще убедитесь, что у вас в $prev, $cur, $sum числовые параметры, иначе будете получать ошибку: Unknown column ... и запрос нужно тогда писать так VALUES (\"{$prev}\",\"{$curr}\",\"{$sum}\")